# AttributeError: module 'pytesseract' has no attribute 'image_to_string'

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-tesseract

```
> import image 
> import pytesseract as pya
> 
> pya.tesseract_cmd = r'C:\Users\Euphz\Documents\Artworks\PSD\Speaking
of Dogs\201710'
> print(pya.image_to_string(image.open('doggieville.png')))
```

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "C:\PythonProjects\pytesseract.py", line 2, in 
>       import pytesseract as pya
>     File "C:\PythonProjects\pytesseract.py", line 5, in 
>       print(pya.image_to_string(image.open('doggieville.png')))
>   AttributeError: module 'pytesseract' has no attribute 'image_to_string'

Why is it happening???

Answer (score 10):

The problem is, you have to rename the python file to something else instead of pytesseract.py . Your python file has the same name as tesseract  inbuilt function .

Comment: Really a lifesaver answer thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Can you try this?

```
import image 
import pytesseract as pya

pya.tesseract_cmd = r'C:\Users\Euphz\Documents\Artworks\PSD\Speaking
of Dogs\201710'
print(pya.image_to_string(image.open('doggieville.png')))
```

The import statements need to be in seperate lines.

Comment: This is for Windows, How do it in Ubuntu?

Comment: Just change the file path